# matching discontinuous/interrupted strings

Tags: python, regex

I have this predefined list of strings that I want to match within a large text file. The problem is that many of these strings do exist in the text, but are interrupted by spurious characters/html-xml tags that I want to keep.

For example, I want to match 'United Nations Headquarters'
and it can exist in the text in the following forms:

```
United Nations & Headquarters
United <br> Nations Headquarters
United Natio<b>ns Hea</b>dquarters
```

I basically need to know the positions of these strings, and I will deal with the spurious characters  later. What I would do for non-interrupted strings is:

```
sting_locations=[v.span() for v in re.finditer(our_string,text)]
```

Can there be some setting for regular expression to ignore these interruptions somehow or what can the solution be?

Comment: Is the file an actual html/xml/something file? Or are there just sometimes XML sequences inside?

Comment: it is an xml file of a word document, and the strings I seek are interrupted by xml tags mainly

Comment: I think it's not really clear what is an acceptable match.  If it can be interrupted as many times as you like, then NPE's very permissive answer works, and this is an acceptable match: "the UNITED NAvigaTors took actIONS to provide HEAvy, Delicious QUARTs of Excellent beeRS to developing nations."

Comment: @femtoRgon you're right, let us focus on strings interrupted by xml tags

Comment: What I want is somehow to let the regex know once it encounters a tag is to stop matching until tag ends, and then continue matching afterwards

Comment: In that case instead of `*?` use something like `(?:<[^>]++>)?`. This will only eliminate one tag though.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

text = """United Nations & Headquarters
United <br> Nations Headquarters
United Natio<b>ns Hea</b>dquarters"""

s = "United Nations Headquarters"

r = re.compile(".*?".join(s))
print([v.span() for v in r.finditer(text)])
```

The key is the `".*?".join(s)`, which inserts `.*?` between every pair of consecutive characters of `s` to turn it into a regex.

You might prefer to tighten the `.*?` up a little if you want to restrict the allowable interruptions.

Comment: Maybe that’s a bit *too* forgiving, but fair enough :P

Comment: interesting solution, but it is taking forever

Comment: Not surprisingly. `.*?` between every character will lead to an enormous amount of backtracking! You ***really, really*** want to tighten it up _a lot_.

Comment: so how to tighten these, some characters are just consecutive, while when there is an interruption, it can be hundreds of characters apart

Comment: @hmghaly - We need to know ***exactly*** what the interruptions could be. Then we _might_ be able to craft an appropriate regex.

Answer (score 1):

Got a couple of solutions which avoid catastrophic backtracking *and* allow any amount of interuptions!

**Solution A**

This is the cleanest solution, but requires the [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (win binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#regex)). It uses atomic grouping, `(?>...)`, to avoid backtracking:

```
import regex

strExampleFile = '''United Nations & Headquarters
United <br> Nations Headquarters
United Natio<b>ns Hea</b>dquarters'''

strSearch = 'United Nations Headquarters'

strRegex = regex.sub(r'((?<!^).)',r'(?>[\s\S]*?(?=\1))\1',strSearch)
rexRegex = regex.compile(strRegex)

print([objMatch.span() for objMatch in rexRegex.finditer(strExampleFile)])
```

**Solution B**

If you neither have installed nor want to install the [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, re *can* be used to imitate atomic grouping. However, the search string is now limited to a maximum of 100 characters:

```
import re

strExampleFile = '''United Nations & Headquarters
United <br> Nations Headquarters
United Natio<b>ns Hea</b>dquarters'''

strSearch = 'United Nations Headquarters'

strRegex = re.sub(r'((?<!^).)',r'(?=([\s\S]*?(?=\1)))\\##\1',strSearch)

for numBackReference in range(1,len(strSearch)) :
    strRegex = strRegex.replace("##", str(numBackReference),1)

rexRegex = re.compile(strRegex)

print([objMatch.span() for objMatch in rexRegex.finditer(strExampleFile)])
```

**Note:** As pointed out by femtoRgon, both of these methods can return false positives.